# pass SSL Structure to a thread

Tags: openssl

Am trying to pass a ssl structure to a thread, but am unable to achieve the same using the below code,

```
   if(SSL_set_fd(ssl, client_s)<0)
    printf("\n error in assigning socket to SSL:");
else
    printf("\n The socket has been assigned to SSL Structure");



    pthread_create (                    /* Create a child thread        */
               &threads,                /* Thread ID (system assigned)  */    
               &attr,                   /* Default thread attributes    */
               my_thread,               /* Thread routine               */
               &ssl);    

}

void *my_thread(void * arg)
{
SSL *ssl1;
ssl1 = *(SSL)arg;
int i=1,err,fh,ret;//i
unsigned int buf_len;
```

the error am getting is as below:

error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you always get a pointer to SSL structure, so here is your corrected code:

```
pthread_create (                    /* Create a child thread        */
           &threads,                /* Thread ID (system assigned)  */    
           &attr,                   /* Default thread attributes    */
           my_thread,               /* Thread routine               */
           ssl);
```

And inside you thread function:

```
void *my_thread(void * arg)
{
    SSL *ssl1;
    ssl1 = (SSL*)arg;
```

You tried to pass "pointer to a pointer" in your 'pthread_create' call and casting inside 'my_thread' was also incorrect.